# Pure JavaScript - Array value gets undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, please be merciful! I'm trying to implement some code, but I've run into a problem.

```js
var edges = [{src: 3, dst: 61}, {src: 46, dst: 40}, {src: 63, dst: 65}, {src: 1, dst: 50}];
var G = [];
var min = 0;
var mini = 0;
var v;
var m = 99;
var n = edges.length;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  G[i] = [];
}
n = edges.length;
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  G[i].push({ 
    l: Infinity, 
    previous: undefined 
  })
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if ( edges[j].src == i ) {
      G[i].push( edges[j].dst ); 
      G[i].sort();
    }
  }
  G[i].unshift(i); 
}
var Q = G;
var u = [];
u = Q[0];
var alt;
Q[0].l = 0;
while ( ( Q.length ) != 0 ) {
  for ( k = 0; k < m ; k++ ) { 
    if ( Q[k].l < min ) {
      mini = Q[k][0];
      u = Q[mini]; 
    }
  }
  Q.splice(mini, 1); 
  m--;

  for (i = 1; i < ( u.length ) ; i++) {
    alt = u.l + 1;
    v = u[i];
    for( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if(Q[j][0] == v) { 
        console.log(v);  
        console.log(Q[j].l);  
        v = j; 
        console.log(v);  
      }
    }


    if (  alt < Q[v].l ){
      Q[v].l = alt;
      Q[v].previous = u;
    }
  }
  mini = 0;
}
```

Here, I get an error in line 52, and it states that "Cannot read property 'l' of undefined in line 55". The value 'l' should be 99999999999999999999 by default, and yet, this disappears. I've been onto this for an hour, could you please help? Why do I get the undefined error?

Comment: Please include the code right in the question, why do we have to click the link?

Comment: `99999999999999999999` is most likely too large, and is processed as `NaN` by the browser.

Comment: You should use more descriptive variable names. The flow of that code is very difficult to follow.

Comment: can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: You might benefit from [this debugging guide](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to follow this pseudocode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
(cannot paste the whole thing, too long).

Comment: Edges is defined, just got cropped. Looks like this:
    `var edges = [{src: 3, dst: 61}, {src: 46, dst: 40}, {src: 63, dst: 65}, {src:    1, dst: 50}]`

Comment: @AMACB 99999 doesn't work either.

Comment: You are getting the error because `Q` is an array with indices `0 to 97`  and you are trying to access a property in that array `v`, but `v` is an object and not one of the indices in that array. That results in undefined, so you can't access property `l` from the undefined object. You could see this pretty easily if you turned on your debugger.

Comment: @dave I have logged to the console, and actually it has no problem running the first n times, but produces the error after running the nth time. You could see this pretty easily if you ran the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that if I'm using

```
G[i].push({ 
    l: Infinity, 
    previous: undefined 
  })
```

it is not possible to access 'l' or 'previous' by `G[i].l`, and thus, it is undefined. Instead I can access it by `G[i][j]["l"]`, since

```
{ 
  l: Infinity, 
  previous: undefined 
}
```

is an element on its own, and I have to access its elements.